# (Multiple inheritance) C++ Create Child class inherits from two classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, visual-c++

The sample code of multiple inheritance below is not working. Please, can you help?

The Child class inherits from the parents classes. Using the show() function in the Child to print out an object value from each parent class.
[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class B
{
    protected:
        string bname;
    public:
        B (string bname1)
            {bname=bname1;}
        string getBName()
            {return bname;}
};
    
class C
{
    protected:
        string cname;
    public:
        C (string cname1)
            {cname=cname1;}
        string getCName()
            {return cname;}
};

class A: public B, public C // MultipleInheritance
{
    private:
        string aname;
    public:
        A ()
            { 
                cout<<"What is the B name? : " << endl ;
                cin >> bname;
                cout << "What is the C name? : " << endl;
                cin >> cname; 
                cout <<"What is the A name? : "<< endl ;
                cin >> aname;
            }
        A (string bname1 , string cname1, string aname1)    
            {bname=bname1; cname=cname1;aname=aname1;}
        string getCName()
            {return cname;}
};

int main ()
{
    A a2 ("parant1","parant2","child1");
    cout<<"constructor >>> parent Name 1 : \t"<< a2.getBName()<<"parent Name 2 : "<< a2.getCName()<<" child Name 1: " <<a2.getAName()<<endl;
}
```

I'm a beginner. Feel free to edit the question to make it simpler.

Comment: Don't use `<string.h>`, its outdated, just use `<string>`

Comment: Also, inherited classes don't have access to their parent class's private elements. Make the fields `fname` and `mname` protected so the child can access it

Comment: Not only is <string.h> outdated, it's the wrong include!  It's the C header for things like `strlen` and `strcmp`, and goes by `<cstring>` in the C++ world.  `<string>` hold the `std:string` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mother` and `Father` each have only one constructor, and that constructor takes a string, so you must supply that string in `Child`'s constructor.

```
public:
    Child (string name, string mname, string fname)
       :Mother(mnane), Father(fname)
    {
         cname = name;
    }
```

Further that code that asks for the names MUST be outside of the constructor (and preferably outside the class entirely)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ***James Curran*** 
If someone wants to check the final code, I hope it helps you.

> This is the new update to the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class Mother 
{
    protected:
        string mname;
    public:
        Mother (string mname1)
            {mname=mname1;}
        string getMName()
            {return mname;}
};

class Father 
{
    protected:
        string fname;
    public:
        Father (string fname1)
            {fname=fname1;}
        string getFName()
            {return fname;}
};

class Child : public Mother, public Father      // MultipleInheritance
{
    private:
        string cname;
    public:
        Child (string mname1 , string fname1, string cname1);
        string getCName();
};

Child :: Child (string mname1, string fname1, string cname1) : Mother(mname1), Father(fname1)
    {cname=cname1;}
string Child :: getCName()
    {return cname;}

void show()     //I use constructor  
{
    Child c2 ("Amneh","Ahmad","Mohammad");
    cout<<"Constructor >>>\n Mother Name : "<< c2.getMName()<<"\n Father Name : "<< c2.getFName()<<"\n Child Name : " <<c2.getCName()<<endl;
}

int main ()
{
    show();
}
```